# Is there a way to add chrome-extension to PuppeteerSharp web driver?

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

How can I load a chrome extension to PuppeteerSharp's driver, 
similar to Selenium's option:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExtension(@"C:\a\path\to\file.zip");
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Line 43 of the LanchOptions.cs](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp/LaunchOptions.cs#L43) you can specify arguments to the launch process.

Now connecting this with the native JavaScript (using the [--load-extension flag](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension)) the output should look similar to the following:

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Args = new string[1] { "--load-extension=/Path/To/Extension/Folder" }
});
```

Note: that I put path to folder, not the .zip as you have in your sample.. if you want to load multiple extensions then just separate the paths using a comma.

[Here's a full list of possible arguments that can be passed in to Chromium.](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issie](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/issues/724), next piece of code works for me:

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Args = new string[1] 
    {
       "--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}",
       "--load-extension=${pathToExtension}"
    }
});
```

Sometimes it can't load some extensions when they are packed (*.crx or *.zip files). Then unpacking this extensions can help.